# Hold requests using injector Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I would like to know if there is a way to hold requests in order to execute them one by one instead of all together?

Request 1 
Request 2
Request 3

If i receive them almost together the idea is to execute Request 1 and after this request is complete then execute the others.

Dont forget i would like to do it using injectors.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to provide code to show that you have attempted this and it failed.

Comment: AngularJS service $injector does not seem to have any kind of support for asynchronous injections. You can download other packages like async-injector or just create yourself a layer over $injector with promises if you like to

Answer (score 0):

You can hold requests using AngularJS Interceptors, by returning a promise in `request` method:

```
authInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$rootScope'];
function authInterceptor($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if(condition) {
                deferred.resolve(config)
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}
```

In this example the requests will hold until meeting some condition.

What you can do is to keep a handle to every request (the `deferred` variable in above example), and send them by resolving each one in your desired order.